# Java Key Adapter Key Event error...semi colon expected instead of parenthesis?

Tags: java, swing, debugging, syntax-error, keylistener

I was following a coding tutorial having to do with Key Events and all the code looks right, but for some reason there is an error that I can't fix. Maybe all I need is another set of eyes to scan through it and spot my error. Here's the code. There are 2 asterisks on either side of the line of code with the error. The error tells me that that a ";" (semicolon) is expected where the
"(" and ")" is...how does that even make sense ? I will also post a picture.

```
package com.Bench3.myGame;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Keying extends JPanel{

public Rectangle character;

public int charW = 24;
public int charH = 36;

public boolean right = false;
public boolean left = false;

public Keying(Display f, Images i){
    character = new Rectangle(180, 180, charW, charH);

    f.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D){
                right = true;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A){
                left = true;
                }

            **public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)**{
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D){
                    right = false;
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A){
                    left = false;
                }
            }
        }
    });     
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(character.x, character.y, character.width, character.height);

    if(right){
        character.x += 1;
    }
    if(left){
        character.x -= 1;
    }
    repaint();
}
```

}
[image: Here's the error up close. hope it helps THANK YOU !]

Comment: your real issue is usage of wrong listener for Swing JComponents, have look at KeyBindings, otherwise you'll focus hunter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to close the curly braces of previous method (`keyPressed()`): -

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D){
            right = true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A){
            left = true;
            }
} // missing
```

Comment: 1+ for solving the problem at hand. On a side note, myself I'd use key bindings not a KeyListener for this type of problem.

Comment: Ahhh never mind, I see now. It is fixed. Thank you. Wow I have a lot more to learn/ I just didn't want to go to bed until this was fixed. Thank you !

Comment: @V1rtualCurry: then edit your original post, showing your new code and your new error messages. We can't read minds  you know and so we haven't a clue what changes you've made or what errors the new code is generating.

Comment: It's all good now guys. Thank you. I don't quite understand the tutorial I'm in (about 10% of it) , but I find that when I jump into the thick of things I learn best. Thank you for your help. Much appreciated ^^

Answer (score 2):

`keyPressed()` method's `}` remaining.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D){
            right = true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A){
            left = true;
            }
}// you missed `}`
```